# Counting every row where certain column is not null or empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a `COUNT` where a certain column should have at least a value. If this column has `EMPTY` or `NULL` value, this should not be included in the `COUNT`. The problem is, I've tried many different SQL functions (e.g.: `IS NOT NULL`, `<>`, `LTRIM`, `RTRIM`, etc...) but rows that don't have values are still included in the count.

For example; in the database I have a column called `MYDESCRIPTION`. There are four records in the table. Two of them have a value in the `MYDESCRIPTION` column, two of them don't. When I look for a count for those that have a value, the other two that don't have are still included in the result. So it is still showing four.

Here are some sample queries within a specific day:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE (CREATIONDATE) >= '2014-12-01' AND
DATE (CREATIONDATE) <= '2014-12-01' AND
MYDESCRIPTION <> ''
```

And

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE (CREATIONDATE) >= '2014-12-01' AND
      DATE (CREATIONDATE) <= '2014-12-01' AND 
      MYDESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL
```

These two simple queries are just some that I have tried. I suppose the query is still counting the column that has no value as it seems like it has a value.

Comment: MySQL... right now im using WinSQL.

Comment: Are you sure lines are empty? What do a explicit SELECt onto this lines show?

Comment: what's the length of all 4 values.  My guess is you have some non-display characters in the data.

Comment: @frlan thats what im not sure. it doesnt have a value so i assumed its empty. how can i check that its empty or null or, NOT empty or null at all even it doesnt have a value?

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause should most likely look like:

```
WHERE DATE (CREATIONDATE) = '2014-12-01'  
  AND MYDESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL
  AND MYDESCRIPTION <> ''
```

Comment: it is still counting all of the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE  
WHERE DATE (CREATIONDATE) >= '2014-12-01' 
AND  DATE (CREATIONDATE) <= '2014-12-01' 
AND (MYDESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL and MYDESCRIPTION <> '')
```

Comment: I know this should be working as this was working for me before... even just the normal COLUMN <> ' '. Right now, it seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUM(CASE...) for situations like this. Adjust the syntax as needed for your DBMS.

```
SELECT 
      SUM(CASE WHEN LENGTH(MYDESCRIPTION) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1) END) AS "Non-Nulls"
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE (CREATIONDATE) >= '2014-12-01' AND
      DATE (CREATIONDATE) <= '2014-12-01' AND 
      MYDESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM
(SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE 1=1
AND (CAST (CREATIONDATE AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST('2014-12-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-12-01' AS DATE) )
AND (MYDESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(TRIM(MYDESCRIPTION)) > 0 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE (CREATIONDATE) >= '2014-12-01'
AND DATE (CREATIONDATE) <= '2014-12-01'
AND (MYDESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL and RTRIM(MYDESCRIPTION) <> '')
```

`IS NOT NULL` is a different condition from `<> ''`.

`IS NOT NULL` means the value is unknown.

`<> ''` means the value is not equal to a ZLS, or Zero Length String.

In adding the `RTRIM`, I was eliminating the possibility of a `CHAR` or `NCHAR` field that was equal to a bunch of spaces, which may or may not be desirable in this OP's question.

Comment: You should really indicate why this addresses the problem: while it may correctly solve it, it is important we understand why.

Comment: MYDESCRIPTION <> x'05' solved the issue. Thanks for the help. :)